# circular reference with FluentValidation causing Stack Overflow Exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I need to validate entities that may have circular references.
When calling the validate method, I get a stackOverflowException.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Twin { get; set; }
}

public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Twin).SetValidator(this);
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bob = new Person { Name = "bob" };
        var bill = new Person { Name = "bill" };
        bob.Twin = bill;
        bill.Twin = bob;
        var result = new PersonValidator().Validate(bob);
    }
}
```

How do I break the circular reference?

Thanks,

Comment: What about removing the `RuleFor` call for Twin and manually validate both `bob` and `bill` before assigning them to each others Twin property?

Comment: unfortunatly, I can't. Validation can occur after the entity has been fully initialized.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, there is one way to break the circular reference. But it need bit coding exercise.

1. First move the RuleFor/SetValidator on Twin from the validator constructor to Initialize method.
2. Have a static object to PersonValidator and call initialize on it. Then use it on SetValidator.

Here is the working version of the validator

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public static readonly PersonValidator PersonValidator1 = new PersonValidator();

    static PersonValidator()
    {
        PersonValidator1.Initialize();
    }

    public PersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Twin).SetValidator(PersonValidator1);
    }
}
```

Comment: this breaks the circular reference but Twin entity is not validated. thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

The code I posted is a very simplified version of the actual code.

The requirements are that validating an entity includes the validation of all its validatable child entities. 
When creating the validator instance, I use reflection to discover validatable child entities and create the rules for them: 
`RuleFor(x => x.Twin).Custom((x, context) => ValidateChildEntity(x, context)`
Worked well, until I hit a case of circular reference.

I was able to break the circular reference by storing in a `Static` object the list of already validated entities. My `ValidateChildEntity` method was then checking that list before calling `Validator.Validate(x)`. But that is not an acceptable solution.

I have tried to play with the `ValidationContext` without success.