# Circular dependency in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I'm using the `FluentValidation` to validate some models.
These models have a circular reference, so i was trying to do something like this:

2 models:

```cs
public class ObjectA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObjectB AnotherObject { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObjectA AnotherObject { get; set; }
}
```

The validadors:

```cs
public class ObjectAValidator : AbstractValidator<ObjectA>
{
    public ObjectAValidator(IValidator<ObjectB> validator)
    {
        this.RuleFor(c => c.Name).NotNull();
        this.RuleFor(c => c.AnotherObject).SetValidator(validator);
    }
}

public class ObjectBValidator : AbstractValidator<ObjectB>
{
    public ObjectBValidator(IValidator<ObjectA> validator)
    {
        this.RuleFor(c => c.Name).NotNull();
        this.RuleFor(c => c.AnotherObject).SetValidator(validator);
    }
}
```

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ObjectA>();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var objetoAValidator = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IValidator<ObjectA>>();

        ObjectA test = new()
        {
            Name = "1Level",
            AnotherObject = new()
            {
                Name = "2Level",
                AnotherObject = new()
                {
                    AnotherObject = new()
                }
            }
        };

        var validationResult = objetoAValidator.Validate(test);
    }
}
```

The code above throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'FluentValidation.IValidator<ConsoleApp9.ObjectA>'.
> FluentValidation.IValidator<ConsoleApp9.ObjectA>(ConsoleApp9.ObjectAValidator) -> FluentValidation.IValidator<ConsoleApp9.ObjectB>(ConsoleApp9.ObjectBValidator) -> FluentValidation.IValidator<ConsoleApp9.ObjectA>'

How can i solve the circular dependency in this case?

Comment: Simplest solution - validate it separately. Grab all obj A and validate the collection, grab B's and also validate collection. Do not assign validator for internal properties holding A or B.
You can also find some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531304/circular-reference-with-fluentvalidation-causing-stack-overflow-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the validator to receive a `IServiceProvider` instead of any other validator, may solve the problem.

To break the circular dependency, you have to check if the model being validated is not null and then validating it using a custom validator.

Exemple:

```cs
public class ObjectBValidator : AbstractValidator<ObjectB>
{
    public ObjectBValidator(IServiceProvider sp)
    {

        this.RuleFor(c => c.Name).NotNull();
        this.RuleFor(c => c.AnotherObject).Custom((value, context) =>
        {
            var validator = sp.GetRequiredService<IValidator<ObjectA>>();
            var r = validator.Validate(value);
            if (!r.IsValid)
            {
                r.Errors.ForEach(context.AddFailure);
            }
        }).When(c => c.AnotherObject is not null);
    }
}
```

It also can be simplified by creating a FluentValidation extension.

```cs
public static IRuleBuilderOptionsConditions<T, TProperty> ValidateInnerType<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilder<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    return ruleBuilder.Custom((value, context) =>
    {
        var validator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IValidator<TProperty>>();
        var r = validator.Validate(value);
        if (!r.IsValid)
        {
            r.Errors.ForEach(context.AddFailure);
        }
    });
}

public class ObjectBValidator : AbstractValidator<ObjectB>
{
    public ObjectBValidator(IServiceProvider sp)
    {
        this.RuleFor(c => c.Name).NotNull();

        this.RuleFor(c => c.AnotherObject)
            .ValidateInnerType(sp)
            .When(c => c.AnotherObject is not null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you inject `IServiceProvider` into your constructor you use *Service Locator Patter* which is not a good solution as it's an anti-pattern. It can lead to run-time errors and unexpected apllication behavior, also it hides a class dependencies which make your code unclear and more difficult to maintain.

The best way to resolve circular dependency is to build your classes dependencies acyclic and make separate validation for both. So i highly recommend you to review your application architecture. But, if you sure that you want to leave it like this, maybe would be better to use **[DataAnnotations attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations)** which can be executed after FluentValidation.

This links can be helpful:

- [The Acyclic Dependencies Principle (ADP, 6p.)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100102145126/http://objectmentor.com/resources/articles/granularity.pdf)
- [Dealing With Circular Dependency Injection References](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/09/14/dealing-with-circular-dependency-injection-references/)

Comment: I think that it can be solved by implementing `validator factories`, so these factories could be injected in the validators.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that whenever you create either object A or objectB, you will always have to create another object.

This essentially creates an infinite loop.

```
    ObjectA test = new()
    {
        Name = "1Level",
        AnotherObject = new ObjectB ()
        {
            Name = "2Level",
            AnotherObject = new ObjectA ()
            {
                Name = "3Level",
                AnotherObject = new ObjectB ()
                {
                  AND SO ON AND SO ON...
                }
            }
        }
    };
```